# I can't understand how to flip this image to its original position

Tags: c, cs50

Basically i need to flip an immage which is reverse in this code, but i don't know how to do it.
In other words, I need to fix this code to flip an image (which is already upside down) back to its original position.

```
}
    // Read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // Read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // Ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    // Write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // Write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // Determine padding for scanlines
    int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    // Iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
    {
        // Iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
        {
            // Temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // Read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(bi.biHeight), 1, inptr);

            // Write RGB triple to outfile
            fwrite(&triple, sizeof(bi.biHeight), 1, outptr);
        }
}
```

So...all i've done is looking in the Microsoft documentation for bit map info ([this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd183376(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) and i found that biHeight might help me to solve the problem reversing from bottom-up to top-down...the problem is that i don't know how to fix the code up here in order to do it.

Comment: Have you tried `bi.biHeight = -bi.biHeight;` leaving the pixel data as it was?

Comment: you mean in the loop, right? btw, i've tried it many times but it is not working at all

Comment: No, not in the loop. Read the header, change the height, write the header. If writing to a new file, copy the rest unchanged.

Comment: yep, just tried but nothing...thank you anyway

Comment: What does "nothing" mean? Please post a clear description of exactly what is happening.

Comment: As you said, i tried to change bi.biHeight, i compiled the program but is wrong again. 
Btw how can i change the height properly?

Comment: Make a copy of the image file. Open it for update with `"rb+"`, read the header, negate the height, seek to the beginning, write the header, close the file.

Answer (score 0):

At least these problems:

- Code fails to read and write the padding per scan line.
- First scan line read in expected to be last one written, 2nd read  written as 2nd to last, etc. - Comments imply a simple height negation is enough.

Comment: I LOVE YOU, 
finally done